# How do i change the hitbox of a symbol to its subsymbol's hitboxes?

Tags: flash, adobe, symbols

So imagine i have a symbol which is a tree, and i want to create a symbol of a forest (many instances of tree). How do i make the hitbox of the forest to be the hitboxes of the trees, instead of a big square around all trees?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a Forest movie clip and within that you have multiple Tree instances. What you want to do is individually check each tree within the forest to see if it collides with your point (or mc or whatever). Here's how you could do that if the forest movie clip is comprised only of tree movie clips:

```
for(var i=0;i<forest.numChildren;i++){
    trace(mc.hitTestObject(forest.getChildAt(i)));
}
```